# Calulating savings between two schemes

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I've normalized a single table to reduce the number of nullable columns from 3 down to 0. The idea was to save a **little** drive space but I'm seeing a 45% decrease in space needed to store the same amount of data between the two schemes but it just seems too good to be true.

**Am I calculating or going about this incorrectly?**

First I'm using this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7892349/550073) to determine size of the tables, so its possible this is the problem.

There is a total of 88324 rows. 1187 are considered root posts and have values for *Title*, *ProductId*, *TotalViews* and have a *NULL* for *ParentPostId*. 87137 are considered replies and have *NULL* for *Title*, *ProductId*, *TotalViews* and have a value for *ParentPostId*.

At any rate the query, linked to above, outputs the following results in Kilobytes which equates to a 45% improvement which seems to big of an improvement to me.

```
+---------+--------+
|Current  |Future  |
+---------+--------+
|94,936   |42,784  |
+---------+--------+
```

My table structure went from a current state of:

[image]

to future state of:

[image]

Comment: Seems like a we thought out thing to do. What sort of answer are you expecting? "Yes"? :P Implement it. Not as if you're dealing with a pen drive worth of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database/7892349#7892349) I was using to calculate space combines indexes and data sizes into one. I used the `sp_spaceused` procedure as well as the below query to track down the the vast size discrepancy to two very large indexes on the *current* state table that I think were created by the tuning adviser. Those two indexes accounted for **60Mb**!!, twice the size of the actual data, lol.

Without those huge indexes *current* state performs horribly while on the other hand *future* state doesn't require any additional indexes to perform as fast if not faster. *Future* state only added about **1.7Mb** increase in storage needs which is far below the *current* states requirements.

**query to find index sizes**:

```
SELECT i.[name] AS IndexName
      ,SUM(s.[used_page_count]) * 8 AS IndexSizeKB 
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS s 
JOIN sys.indexes AS i 
ON s.[object_id] = i.[object_id] 
AND s.[index_id] = i.[index_id] 
GROUP BY i.[name] 
ORDER BY i.[name] 
GO
```

**result shows two huge indexes:**

[image: query result]

**`sp_spaceused 'Post_Old'` result confirms that the those two indexes account for the discrepancy:**

[image: sp_spaceused]

Answer (score 0):

Your denormalised environment may have indexes you're not considering, to help performance... I doubt you're comparing like with like right now.

There is a price to pay in joining those tables, and you may find that heavy querying is a higher load now. But inserts and updates are going to be nicer.